# Does the nVidia Titan V support GPUDirect?

Tags: cuda, nvidia-titan

I was wondering if someone might be able to help me figure out if the new Titan V from nVidia support GPUDirect. As far as I can tell it seems limited to Tesla and Quadro cards.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: You can use GPUDirect peer to peer between two Titan V cards if you have the proper system configuration/topology.  You cannot use GPUDirect RDMA.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Sounds like an answer. kuwze: You should be able to look these things up on nVIDIA's website. I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GPUDirect](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect) Peer-to-Peer (P2P) is supported between any 2 "like" CUDA GPUs (of compute capability 2.0 or higher), if the system topology supports it, and subject to other requirements and restrictions. In a nutshell, the system topology requirement is that both GPUs participating must be enumerated under the same PCIE root complex.  If in doubt, "like" means **identical**.  Other combinations may be supported (e.g. 2 GPUs of the same compute capability) but this is not specified, or advertised as supported.  **If in doubt, try it out.** Finally, these things must be "discoverable" by the GPU driver.  If the GPU driver cannot ascertain these facts, and/or the system is not part of a whitelist maintained in the driver, then P2P support will not be possible.

Note that in general, P2P support may vary by GPU or GPU family.  The ability to run P2P on one GPU type or GPU family does not necessarily indicate it will work on another GPU type or family, even in the same system/setup.  The final determinant of GPU P2P support are the tools provided that query the runtime via `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer`.  So the statement here "is supported" should not be construed to refer to a particular GPU type.  P2P support can vary by system and other factors as well.  No statements made here are a guarantee of P2P support for any particular GPU in any particular setup.

GPUDirect RDMA is only supported on Tesla and possibly some Quadro GPUs.

So, if you had a system that had 2 Titan V GPUs plugged into PCIE slots that were connected to the same root complex (usually, except in Skylake CPUs, it should be sufficient to say "connected to the same CPU socket"), and the system (i.e. core logic) was recognized by the GPU driver, I would expect P2P to work between those 2 GPUs.

I would not expect GPUDirect RDMA to work to a Titan V, under any circumstances.

YMMV.  If in doubt, try it out, before making any large purchasing decisions.

Comment: I was hoping to use GPUDirect for accessing a SSD.